# Condensing several if statements into a for and an if

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to condense these four if statements into a for loop and with a single if condition? I was told that there is a way but I can only think of multiple else if statements.

```
function New() {
  if (foodInOven == true) {
    timeOfCooking += 1;
  }
  if (timeOfCooking == 10) {
    console.log("cooked pasta");
  } else if (timeOfCooking == 15) {
    console.log("burning pasta!");
  } else if (timeOfCooking == 20) {
    console.log("pasta burnt!!");
  }
}
```

Comment: A [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) might be easier.

Answer (score 5):

One option could be to have a lookup for your times and, if there's a value, log it to the console.

```js
const cookingLookup = {
  10: "cooked pasta",
  15: "burning pasta!",
  20: "pasta burnt!!"
}

function New() {
  if (foodInOven == true) {
    timeOfCooking += 1;
  }
  if (cookingLookup[timeOfCooking]) {
    console.log(cookingLookup[timeOfCooking]);
  }
}
```

Comment: but that's 2 if statements, I was looking for 1 for and 1 if

Comment: @JuanDraper seeing this solution, why do you need a for loop?

Comment: You could use a short circuit operation on the first part if you really want to get rid of the first if. `foodInOven == true && timeOfCooking += 1`. But seems a bit silly to aim for a certain number of `if` statements and a `for` loop.

Comment: @Taplar My TA recommended that I try implementing a for loop but I just didn't see a way to apply it. It's just to look at the problem from all angles.

Comment: A `for` loop is related to looping of some sort.  Nothing presented in your OP was related to looping.  Unless you are meaning to loop the call to that function from some number to some other number.  If that is the case, then that detail is missing from the question.  Otherwise, no, looping doesn't make sense here.